# Razor RenderPartial generates wrong HTML

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I have a page Item Edit with multiple partial rendered forms for images delete. Item Edit page:

```
@model EditModel
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="ItemModel.Id" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ItemModel.AllOtherFields" type="hidden" />
</form>
@if (Model.ItemModel.ImageViewModels != null && Model.ItemModel.ImageViewModels.Any())
{
    foreach(var imageViewModel in Model.ItemModel.ImageViewModels)
    {
       Html.RenderPartial("ItemImage/_itemImageEdit", imageViewModel);
    }
}
```

ItemImage/_itemImageEdit

```
@model ViewModels.ItemImageViewModel

<form asp-controller="Images" asp-action="Delete" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
    <img src="@Url.Action("Get", "Images", new { id = Model.Id })" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

and here is my strange final html

```
<form method="post" action="/Images/Delete/5" novalidate="novalidate">
     <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" value="5">
     <img src="/Images/Get/10">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Where 5- Item id and 10 - image Id. So this is expected and correct

```
<img src="/Images/Get/10">
```

while this is not. Item Id used instead of id (ItemImageViewModel.id)

```
action="/Images/Delete/5"
```

I have no idea why does `@Model.Id`generate different ids on the same subview.

Edit1:

```
public class ItemImageViewModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel()
    {
    }
    public ItemViewModel(ItemViewModel vm)
    {
        Id = vm.Id;
        Title = vm.Title;
        ImageViewModels = vm.ImageViewModels;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemImageViewModel> ImageViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

I have removed unrelated fields.
Debugger shows alright
[image: Debugger shows alright]

Comment: Show your model definition.

Comment: @CodeCaster updated

Answer (score 0):

Now this weird piece of code generates what it supposed to generate

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Delete", "Images", new { id = Model.Id })" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Id)" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ItemId)"
    <img src="@Url.Action("Get", "Images", new { id = Model.Id })" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Title" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>


<form action="/Images/Delete/10" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="10">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The ItemId field is required." id="ItemId" name="ItemId" type="hidden" value="5">"
    <img src="/Images/Get/10">
    <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" value="Jacket">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

[image: what received]